# Generating data objects in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, command-line, zend-tool

Is there any way to create data objects for MySQL database tables using `Zend_Tool`?

What I am trying to achieve is to create setter/getter methods and column variable of any table in some class by using command line zf utility. (like we can do it in pear)

Comment: Have you read the manual about the model and database generation with ZF_TOOL? If not, see if is it what you are looking for ... http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create your own providers for Zend_Tool.

Essentially, you create a class that extends `Zend_Tool_Project_Provider_Abstract`. Every public method becomes an action available within the `zf.sh` tool.

You also need to register your new provider with Zend_Tool. Do this by running:

1. run `zf --setup storage-directory`
2. run `zf --setup config-file`
3. edit `~/.zf.ini` and add `php.include_path` and `basicloader.classes.0` entries that point to your new provider's path and classname respectively.

Further details: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/akrabat_db_schema_manager-zend-framework-database-migrations/ & https://github.com/akrabat/Akrabat/blob/master/zf1/Akrabat/Tool/DatabaseSchemaProvider.php